# Unable to create a import module

Tags: python

I was having trouble with circular dependencies, only to find some advice online that I'm better off importing an entire module rather than specific items within a module. Prior to the circular dependency issue, I was having no issue with imports.

So with the blog's advice, I setup a `__init__.py` in a folder containing a few models, imported each there, and now when I try to import from that module, I'm being told that module doesn't have an attribute I'm looking for.

So I have this file structure:

```
└── root
    ├── models
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── a.py
    │   └── b.py
    └── c.py
```

In `__init__.py`, I have

```
from models.a import A
from models.b import B
```

And in `c.py`

```
import models

# code

models.A.func()
```

But I get the error `module 'models' has no attribute 'A'`. As A and B both reference each other, I was getting circular imports at first, but now that they're resolved, I can't get the models to show up at all.

Comment: How do you run your code? IDE or command line? Do you have the PYTHONPATH environment variable set? If so, what is it's value?

Comment: Use `print(models)` to make sure it's importing the right one.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice It's in a docker instance running gunicorn. The root is in the `PYTHONPATH`, and until I ran into this circular import issue, I wasn't having any issues importing anything.

Comment: Is this a Django project? Is `models` really in the project root? Or do you have `project/app/models`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice It's actually a flask app, but I'm using the Django model engine. So yah, it's in the structure you mentioned. I didn't think it mattered, so I simplified the code for the sake of the question.

Comment: @Rohit Yes, flask/django doesn't really matter here. The only thing that matters is the  directory structure of your project, so I just wanted to clarify that what you have in your post acurately reflects reality. In my Django projects, my structure is typeically `project_root/app/models` with `project_root` in  PYTHONPATH. The import is `from app import models` or `from . import models` rather than just `import models`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The root is in the `PYTHONPATH`, so I'll try your first suggestion and see how it turns out. Thanks.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Tried both ways you suggested, neither worked :/ Guess it's back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to add your project's directory to `PYTHONPATH` or you need to do

```
from . import models
```

Comment: So I have to add every subdirectory to the `PYTHONPATH`? I already have the root in the `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: @Rohit No, just the project's root directory.

Answer (score 0):

your `__init__.py` file doesn't require any change. I think in c.py file, type as follows :

```
modele_name.function_name()
```

If u have imported that function in your `__init__.py` file, this will help you, I suppose.
For more details, please edit your question and add the git link of your repo